# Printing from grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
printenv > grep 'desktop'> echo var
```

I tried running this in the terminal in an attempt to print the occurences where *desktop* was mentioned in the output of printenv command. I'm new here and would like help with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, `>` is for redirecting output to a file.  To redirect output to be used as input to another command, you want the "pipe" operator, `|` :

```
printenv | grep 'desktop'
```